# PyQt QApplication.aboutToQuit()

Tags: python, pyqt4

I'm trying to catch the global about to quit signal from my application class which subclasses QApplication. Here is how I attempt to set it up in main.

```
def cleanUp():
    os.system('rosnode kill -a')
    sys.exit(0)

## Start Qt event loop
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Application(sys.argv)
    app.aboutToQuit.connect(cleanUp)
    app.exec_()
```

The issue is that this doesn't seem to catch the signal I have apparently connected.

### Edit

I'm using PyQtGraph, so preferably is there some way to catch global window closes?

```
# The main application
class Application(QtGui.QApplication):

    def __init__(self, args):
        QtGui.QApplication.__init__(self, args)
        self.plot = pg.plot(title="UWB")
        self.raw_signal = self.plot.plot()
        self.filtered_signal = self.plot.plot()
        # Start the main loop
        self.listen()
```

Comment: That code seems to work for me if I print a line within the cleanUp method.

Answer (score 2):

You can also override the close event when your `QMainWindow` is closed. That might be just as useful depending on your use case.

```
# override exit event
def closeEvent(self, event):

    cleanUp()

    # close window
    event.accept()
```

**Edit:** This minimal example works for me; 'closing' is printed when the plot window is closed.

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sys

# The main application
class Application(QtGui.QApplication):

    def __init__(self, args):
        QtGui.QApplication.__init__(self, args)
        self.plot = pg.plot(title="UWB")

    def cleanUp(self):
        print 'closing'

## Start Qt event loop
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Application(sys.argv)
    app.aboutToQuit.connect(app.cleanUp)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: that only applies if I inherit from QWidget, which I don't because I need to use QApplication

Comment: Can I globally catch a window close? I'm using PyQtGraph that probably is creating a widget for me.

Comment: Are you adding a PlotWidget to a layout? If so you should be able to catch the window containing the layout closing using this method.

Comment: I think I am, I call self.plot = pg.plot(title="UWB"). But it doesn't seem to catch it.

Comment: Can you add more code to your question so it's more complete? Hard to tell otherwise.

Comment: added my init to question

Comment: You can't use `closeEvent` as you don't have a layout. You could add one if you wanted. BUT, your code works for me. Perhaps `cleanUp` is not doing what you expect it to do?

Comment: hmm, well it doesn't execute a print at the top of cleanUp for me, I guess there must be something else happening behind the scenes.

Comment: I did take out the sys.exit() in mine, I'll give try put that back in

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?

Comment: nope, i just ended up deciding to catch ctrl-c and kill of things with that.